# Why would you set the same values in Required-start as you did for Required-stop in a init.d script?

Tags: debian, init.d

[The Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) gives the following example for 'INIT INFO`:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

Then the documentation says the following about Required-stop:

> **Required-Stop**: boot_facility_1 [boot_facility_2...]
>
> defines facilities used by the service
>   provided by the script. The facility
>   provided by this script should stop
>   before the listed facilities are
>   stopped to avoid conflicts. *Normally
>   you would include here the same
>   facilities as for the Required-Start
>   keyword.*

Isn't it pointless to set the same values to `Required-Start` if it's not going to run until the facility is stopped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Required-Stop**: boot_facility_1
>   [boot_facility_2...]
>
> defines facilities used by the service provided by the script. The
>   facility provided by this script
>   **should stop before** the listed
>   facilities are stopped to avoid
>   conflicts. Normally you would include
>   here the same facilities as for the
>   Required-Start keyword.

**Required-Stop** is used to indicate that listed facilities should not be stopped before the ones provided by the current script are stopped.

This is to prevent, for example, $remote_fs from being stopped and your NFS mounted /usr and /var being unmounted before your database server has a chance to shutdown safely and properly save the database to the filesystem.

Comment: Ohh, I see what my confusion was. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

An additional example:  I run VirtualBox inside a VNC server, started by two different init scripts.

I want the VirtualBox to close before VNC.  Because if VNC closes first, VirtualBox may be killed instead of shutting down cleanly!

So I specify that my VirtualBox init scripts depends on VNC for starting up, and also for closing down.